# visibility CSS with simple if else if statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, if-statement, visibility

I'm trying to validate user input with a regex. If the user doesn't fill the field, it shows the error "please fill in the field". The problem is that if the user doesn't fill the field, the second error will also be displayed. How can I stop this from happening? This is what I tried:

```
if (!regex.test($('#fname').val())) {
            $("#err2fname").removeClass("hidden"); //displays error if it doesn't match the regex
    }
    else if ($("#fname").val() == "" ) {
        $("#err2fname").addClass("hidden"); //hides if field is empty
    }
    else ($("#err2fname").addClass("hidden")); //hides if it matches the regex
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb2Tv/) that shows my problem.

Comment: Your cascading if, else, else if logic is confusing.  I recommend that you always use braces `{}` even when the code inside the conditional is just one line.  And some comments in the code would be nice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see where I am missing braces, I always use them even if it's only for one statement

Comment: Change `else ($("#err2fname").addClass("hidden"));` to `else { $("#err2fname").addClass("hidden") };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if ($("#fname").val() == "") {
        $("#errfname").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#err2fname").addClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $("#errfname").addClass("hidden");
        if (!regex.test($('#fname').val())) {
            $("#err2fname").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $("#err2fname").addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
```

I have updated your fiddle. Please try looking at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb2Tv/12/)

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it does the same thing as before, as if the field is empty it will display "err2fname"?

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeBaillargeon i have updated my answer and that should work.

Comment: Oh that's clever! I should have thought about handling the two errors in the same if clause. Oh well, i'm still learning! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#fname").blur(function () {
    $("#errfname").toggleClass("hidden", this.value != "");
    $("#err2fname").toggleClass("hidden", !regex.test(this.value) && this.value.length);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrHGX/1/